# Unable to locate image viewers that integrate geotag information into the viewing experience

Tags: images, image-viewer, geotagging

I'm kind of surprised this is not easy, so I might be looking for the wrong thing.

I have a folder full of images that all have GPS location data embedded in them.  I'd like to find an image viewer that makes it easy to view the image and a map of where the image was taken.

The problem I'm having is that when I search for it, I don't come up with much.  Most of the hits are for *geotagging your images* rather than *viewing the location of a geotagged image*.

What should I be searching for?  Or is there a go-to application for the desktop that everybody already knows you should be using to view geotagged images?

Answer (score 1):

[GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de) is an amazing free portable Windows app that has a fantastic user interface and shows your folder (and optionally subfolders) on a Map including Google Maps, OpenStreetMap.org, and MyTopo etc.

Answer (score 0):

Picasa does an OK job.. but i haven't found an amazing app yet..

Comment: Picasa is now discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [QGIS](http://qgis.org/).  It's a free & open source GIS software, but it allows you to import files or folders and view them as points on a map through a plugin called [ImportPhotos](https://mariosmsk.com/2019/07/02/qgis-plugin-importphotos/) which you can add from the toolbar menu.  Each point becomes clickable.  A data table is also generated with coordinates, which you can use to browse the photos.